# SignalR ApplicationUserManager is disposed while using webSockets transport

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, websocket, signalr, asp.net-identity

I've added SignalR to my existing MVC project and tried to use the same ApplicationUserManager from MVC to load user into hub context.

After connection is done, I call some server method like this:

```
        var alertsHub = $.connection.monitoringHub;

        $(function() {
            alertsHub.client.processAlertChange = function (name, alert) {
                console.log(alert);
            };

            //start the connection
            $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                console.log("Connected, transport = " + $.connection.hub.transport.name);
                alertsHub.server.subscribeToMonitor();
            });
        });
```

In my Hub method there is a call

```
CurrentUser = ConnectedUsers.GetOrAdd(this.Context.ConnectionId, UserManager.FindByName(this.Context.User.Identity.Name));
```

where UserManager is property just like this

```
        protected static ConcurrentDictionary<string, ApplicationUser> ConnectedUsers = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, ApplicationUser>();

    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            if (_userManager == null)
            {
                _userManager = Context.Request.GetHttpContext().GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
            }
            return _userManager;
        }
    }
    protected ApplicationUser CurrentUser { get; set; }
```

The problem is that when webSockets transport is used I'm getting an error 'Cannot access disposed object'

```
SignalR: webSockets transport connected. Initiating start request.
SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
SignalR: Now monitoring keep alive with a warning timeout of 13333.333333333332, keep alive timeout of 20000 and disconnecting timeout of 300000
Connected to monitoringHub, transport = webSockets
SignalR: Invoking monitoringhub.SubscribeToMonitor
SignalR: monitoringhub.SubscribeToMonitor failed to execute. Error: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'ApplicationUserManager'.
```

BUT! When I force serverSentEvents transport - there is no error and everything works great. Why? And how it can be fixed...

My Startup.cs

```
            ConfigureAuth(app);

        // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
        var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration();
        hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;

        app.MapSignalR("/sr", hubConfiguration);

        GlobalHost.HubPipeline.RequireAuthentication();
        GlobalHost.Configuration.ConnectionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(120);
        GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(300);
        GlobalHost.Configuration.KeepAlive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at it in a proxy like Fiddler?

Comment: This error is occurring on the server because of a disposed Identity object.  Fiddler, Postman, etc. will only see what the server responds.  In this case, Postman may receive a 500 server error.  That response would be due to the particular implementation.  Fiddler may not be helpful.

Comment: ApplicationUserManager is a scoped service? As you are getting it from Context.Request i belive so. So when you try to get the object it already been disposed. Try change this line `CurrentUser = ConnectedUsers.GetOrAdd(this.Context.ConnectionId, UserManager.FindByName(this.Context.User.Identity.Name));` to actually get the UserManager on the execution other than using properties.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you use auth token (Bearer or something else). SignalR is not sending auth token to the server by default. So, Context is empty. See Microsoft documentation on
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0

```
    // Connect, using the token we got.
this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/hubs/chat", { accessTokenFactory: () => this.loginToken })
    .build();
```

After you will add accessTokenFactory (on the client side), SignalR will include token value to the Request.Query param as 'access_token' and there is no possibility to change 'access_token' name to another name (e.g. 'token'). So, you need to implement an additional handler or middleware to auth and fill Context on your backend.

```
context.Request.Query["access_token"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps:

1. Turn on Streaming in Fiddler.
2. If your SignalR transport is WebSockets, requests may take a few seconds to come through while Fiddler is on.

Answer (score 0):

With a WebSockets SignalR connection, the initial tcp connection is upgraded to a ws connection.  The UserManager context is disposed after the Hub connection is upgraded and initialized.

I would recommend using an OAuth Bearer Token approach.  Rather than calling this.Context.User.Identity.Name in each SignalR method, obtain the UserName from the bearer token.

Microsoft documentation shows an example of this:
[Bearer token authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-5.0)